# How to validate nested xml namespaces with associated schemata in nxml?

Tags: nxml, xml, xml-schema

I often use emacs to edit oozie workflow/coordinator definitions and nxml mode is pretty handy for that. I never bothered much to get more than basic xml validation since schema-based validation seemed too complex to set up for me. But it turns out once I figured how to convert the provided xsd schemas to rnc (with the help of http://debeissat.nicolas.free.fr/XSDtoRNG.php and [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) and some hand editing) it's actually quite easy by adding the correct path to the `schema.xml`.

E.g. I can add this line

```
<namespace ns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1" uri="workflow-0.1.rnc"/>
```

and so every xml which has the `xmlns` attribute `uri:oozie:workflow:0.1` gets validated with the `workflow-0.1.rnc` schema. The sad thing is that this is only working for root elements, but oozie supports "Actions Extensions" with its one namespace and schema. E.g.

```
[...]
<action name="sendFailureEmail">
    <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
        <to>${toEmailAlias}</to>
        <subject>...</subject>
        <body>...</body>
    </email>
    <ok to="fail"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
[...]
```

All three subelements of `email` (`to`, `subject` and `body`) are marked as "invalid" in nxml because they are not specified in the workflow-0.1.rnc schema. I also generated the rnc version of the email-action schema and put in

```
<namespace ns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1" uri="email-action-0.1.rnc"/>
```

into my `schema.xml` but that doesn't help since it only applies for root elements.

Is there an easy way to get nxml to recognize nested namespaces for validation or is this simply an unsupported feature?

Comment: I don't know if nxml can do that, but if it can't, then it should be extended to support it, since this can occur in various kinds of XML documents.  So I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` asking for this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But then the question is if it's really appropriate to use this channel for a feature request (since it's arguably not a bug if it's just not officially supported). Maybe I should try the mailing list?

Comment: I was the head maintainer of Emacs until a few months ago, so you can believe me on this.  `M-x report-emacs-bug` is the normal channel for feature requests.